# IOS Development Shaking Gesture

Tags: swift, ios8

In Swift IOS app Development I need help with the code for:

When I get the app going I need the function for resetting the app back to the start once I shake the device on the last view controller. It's a simple magic 8 app that I have the code for, but I'm stuck once you get to the last view controller. How do I set it up for once I shake the device it resets back to the main view controller? Thank You in Advance!

I added code**

```
import UIKit

class thirdViewController: UIViewController {
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Shaky Shaky")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "thirdViewSegue", sender: self)      
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." even if it is no homework.

Comment: Yes sir, I will share as soon as I get home! Thank You!

Comment: Hey Guys just got home from work, I added the code you guys where asking for, Thank You soooo Very Much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm make a lot of assumptions here, since you haven't shared any of your code, but here goes... In the 'last view controller'

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override fun motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
       self.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Beside to override and set `canBEcomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Typo above - 'Be sure to override and set...'